# WKWebView WKScriptMessageHandler not called with iOS 10, Xcode 8 beta

Tags: wkwebview, swift3, xcode8

I need to update my code to swift 3. The code below is the original solution what is works perfectly, but in Xcode 8 beta and iOS 10 with swift 3 the `userContentController` delegate does not called when I use the original html+js code to call the native side.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKScriptMessageHandler, WKNavigationDelegate,UIWebViewDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate,URLSessionDataDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

....

func initWebView(){
    // JAVASCRIPT PART
    let contentController = WKUserContentController();

    let jScript:String = "var meta = document.createElement('meta'); meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport'); meta.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width'); document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);";

    let wkUScript:WKUserScript = WKUserScript(source: jScript, injectionTime: WKUserScriptInjectionTime.atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true);


    contentController.addUserScript(wkUScript)
    contentController.add(
        self,
        name: "refreshWebPage"
    )
    contentController.add(
        self,
        name: "forceStepBack"
    )
    contentController.add(
        self,
        name: "setPageTitle"
    )
    contentController.add(
        self,
        name: "allowBackNavigate"
    )
    contentController.add(
        self,
        name: "changeBackNavigationURL"
    )

    contentController.add(
        self,
        name: "changeLeftButtonIconVisibility"
    )
    contentController.add(
        self,
        name: "changeRightButtonIconVisibility"
    )
    contentController.add(
        self,
        name: "clearWebCache"
    )
    contentController.add(
        self,
        name: "changeMobileAndPassword"
    )


    let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    config.userContentController = contentController


    self.webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect.zero, configuration: config)


    self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.webView!.navigationDelegate = self
    self.webView!.uiDelegate = self;
    self.webView!.scrollView.bounces = false;
    view = webView

    webView?.loadHTMLString(self.baseURL!, baseURL: nil)

}
...
func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        print("JavaScript is sending a message: \(message.body)")
        print("JavaScript is sending a message.name: \(message.name)")

    }
```

Comment: me too, not finding any solutions... HELP!

Answer (score 9):

Afer I debug a lot of times and conditions , I found that :

> 1. The function `postMessage()` in your JS must have a **parameter**, the **parameter** never be null
> 2. The **parameter** must be `JSON` type
> 3. For example :
>    `webkit.messageHandlers.refreshWebPage.postMessage("status":"ok");`

If you have followed the three advices above and have the delegate set correct. The delegate function `didReceiveScriptMessage` will be called. Hope this help you.

Comment: For clarification there is no delegate to be set. `func userContentController(WKUserContentController, didReceive: WKScriptMessage)` is a method from the `WKScriptMessageHandler` protocol which gets called by the system.

Answer (score 4):

Do you find the way to fix it? because I have a problem also but Fortunately, I could send the message and userContentController did called back but only message has to be in number only, no string, no characters. I don't know why...

**Edited** 
I have found out the answer about this. 
It's seem that you have to put in try catch and after I did that it's 100% working with text number or even json

```
`<script>
    function callNative(message)  {
    try {
        webkit.messageHandlers.callbackHandler.postMessage(message)
    } catch(err) {
        console.log("Error")
    }
    }
</script>`
```

And Don't forget that `callbackHandler` has to be the same word in the iOS to make it work, you don't have to name callbackHandler, you could name it anything but it has to be the same in both Javascript and iOS

Hope it helps you

Comment: I also experience issues with WKScriptMessageHandler not being called on iOS 10. I posted the issue on the Apple Developer Forums: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/180962

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this by only having one contentController like

```
let contentController = WKUserContentController()
contentController.add(self, name: "MyStuff")
```

Then in the userContentController function I parse the body to determine the requested action and other parameters.  If I send {action: "doThis", params: [1,2,3]}, my parsing code would be like:

```
if message.name == "MyStuff" {
    let cmd:NSDictionary = message.body as! NSDictionary
    let action:String = cmd["action"] as! String
    switch action {
    case "doThis":
        // Do my stuff
        break
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's happened because basically `window.webkit.messageHandlers` is a `UserMessageHandlersNamespace` type.

You should try to pass a dictionary instead of a string or an array:

JavaScript part:

```
var dictionary = {"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2", "subDictionary": {"name": "foo"}}
webkit.messageHandlers.refreshWebPage.postMessage(dictionary);
```

Swift part:

```
func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        let body = message.body
        if let dict = body as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
            if let test = dict["key1"] {
                print("JavaScript is sending a message \(value1)")
            }
        }
}
```

**P.S.** (This works on both iOS9, iOS10 according with my tests)

Comment: Thanks Alessandro - passing a string was working for me sometimes, not on the sim though - passing an array works - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if from JS it's not used webkit.messageHandlers.refreshWebPage

```
webkit.messageHandlers.refreshWebPage.postMessage("status":"ok")
```

then you can wrap it at `WKUserContentController` like below so you will get call back from the method

```
    let userController = WKUserContentController() 
    let channelName = "postMessage"
    let wrapperSource = "window.\(channelName) = webkit.messageHandlers.\(channelName);"
    let wrapperScript = WKUserScript(
        source: wrapperSource,
        injectionTime: .atDocumentStart,
        forMainFrameOnly: false)
    userController.addUserScript(wrapperScript)
    userController.add(self, name: "postMessage")
    let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    configuration.userContentController = userController
    self.wkWebView = WKWebView(
               frame: self.view.bounds,
               configuration: configuration
           )
```